# How to execute function on dictionary in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a JSON file that I would like to convert all date strings to date types.  Now my script loops through the JSON dictionary and write these values to a database.  How would I execute my string to date conversion on an entire dictionary?

My code snippet is here which loops through the objects.   I would like to convert my CreatedDate output from   `"02/17/2015 16:53:25"`
to `"2015-02-17 16:53:25"`

Now I am using  `CreatedDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(CreatedDate, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")` to achieve the latter output, how would I execute this on the below code snipped for CreateDate

```
for sr in decoded2['Response']['ListOfServiceRequest']['ServiceRequest']:
    SRAddress = sr['SRAddress']
    Latitude = sr['Latitude']
    Longitude = sr['Longitude']
    SRNumber = sr['SRNumber']
    FirstName = sr['FirstName']
    LastName = sr['LastName']
    HomePhone = sr['HomePhone']
    CreatedDate = sr['CreatedDate']
```

Comment: I'm not sure I get the question, what doesn't work when you put your `strptime` call just after getting `CreatedDate`? (or even on `sr['CreatedDate']`)?

Comment: I think you're right, perhaps I over thought this one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstand, but can you not simply use `strftime` to convert your date back to a string with the required format?

```
def convert_date_string(s_date_in):
    date_in = datetime.datetime.strptime(s_date_in, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    return datetime.datetime.strftime(date_in, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

for sr in decoded2['Response']['ListOfServiceRequest']['ServiceRequest']:
    sr['CreatedDate'] = convert_date(sr['CreatedDate'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your initial structure is a JSON string you could write a custom [JSONDecoder](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders) and inspect the string to see whether to determine whether or not it can is a date string.

Alternatively you can use the [object_hook](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/json.html#json.load) kwarg and pass it a custom function. EG:

```
json_string = '{"key": "02/17/2015 16:53:25", "key2": {"nest": 1,"nest2": "blah"}}'
import json

def obj_hook(dct):
    for k, v in dct.iteritems():
        if isinstance(v, basestring):
            # Put your date time detection here. Also add additional type checks.
            dct[k] = 'Replaced-- {}'.format(v)
    return dct

result_dict = json.loads(json_string, object_hook=obj_hook)

print result_dict
>>> {u'key2': {u'nest': 1, u'nest2': 'Replaced-- blah'}, u'key': 'Replaced-- 02/17/2015 16:53:25'}
```

This might be overkill if all you want is to change the value of the dictionary in place. As xnx's answer indicates you can mererly change the value of the dictionary within the loop.